# I Want to make function in different class(outside my form) for my first-Next-Previous-Last buttons for my All forms with same buttons

Tags: c#

I Want to make function in different class(outside my form) for my first-Next-Previous-Last buttons for my All forms with same buttons .

How should I do it ? no Idea to access textboxes in other class.

My Code is here for Next button !!

```
 <pre lang="c#">   
private void CmdNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
           ConStr Constring = new ConStr();
           String CS = Constring.ConString("DBCS"); 
           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
           {
               SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from FeesHead order by ID", con);

               DataSet DS = new DataSet();
               DA.Fill(DS, "FeesHead");

               if ( i < DS.Tables["FeesHead"].Rows.Count-1)
               {
                   i++;
                   this.TxtID.Text = DS.Tables["FeesHead"].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                   this.TxtFees.Text = DS.Tables["FeesHead"].Rows[i]["Fees"].ToString();
                   this.TxtFeesHead.Text = DS.Tables["FeesHead"].Rows[i]["FeesHead"].ToString();
                   this.TxtRemarks.Text = DS.Tables["FeesHead"].Rows[i]["Remarks"].ToString();

                   if (i == DS.Tables["FeesHead"].Rows.Count - 1)
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("This is Last Record"); 
                   }<pre lang="c#">
```

I am Trying Class library for above procedure My code is here !! I need some corrections !! I feed difficulty to access my form text box here so I left blank this space !!

```
//
`public void move_prev(String Con_String, String Table)
        {
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Con_String))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + Table +"", con);

                    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                    DA.Fill(DS, Table);

                    for (int j=0; j<= DS.Tables[Table].Columns.Count;j++ )
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        String name_of_column = DS.Tables[Table].Columns[j].ColumnName;

                        if (i == DS.Tables[Table].Rows.Count - 1 || i != 0)
                        {
                            i--;

                               = DS.Tables[Table].Rows[i][name_of_column].ToString();


                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("This is First Record");
                            }

                        }
                    }
              }}
           }
        }
    }

`//
```

Comment: Do not access the textbox from the new method. Pass the value of the text box _into_ the method, in a parameter.

Comment: but how to pass text box value as parameter there are many text boxes and I want to make one method to use like this forms !! my all forms contains first-next-prev-last buttons

Comment: If you don't know how to pass a parameter to a method, then you need to  study a bit. There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: what to write before this line !! any clue = DS.Tables[Table].Rows[i][name_of_column].ToString();

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: what I have tried ? I mentioned already in my question sir !!

Answer (score 1):

You *should* try to have business logic in a separate class from the UI logic.  I'm sure you've encountered the terms Model View Controller (MVC), Model View Presenter (MVP) and Model View, ViewModel (MVVM), all of which are approaches to achieving this.

In the context of this question, a simplified version of this can be achieved by encapsulating the 'first-prev-next-last' last logic in a business logic class and attaching an instance of it to the form class, (where attachment might be done via a factory class or method.)  The business logic class exposes methods and properties that the UI form class can access.

```
public interface INavigation
{
    // Property mapping field names to values
    public Dictionary<string,string> CurrentRecordFields;

    public void FirstRecord(void);
    // ... plus all the other navigation methods.
}
```

The use of an interface here has several advantages: you can create a mock class for unit testing purposes, or you might have different implementations of the interface (for different tables in the database for example) any of which can re-use the same UI.

```
public class Navigation : INavigation
{
    // Properties from INavigator
    public Dictionary<string,string> CurrentRecordFields {get; set;}

    // private fields
    private string conString;
    private string tableName;

    // Constructor requires that the connection string and
    // required table name be passed as arguments.
    public Navigation(String Con_String, String Table)
    {
        conString = Con_String;
        tableName = Table;
        CurrentRecordFields = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }

    // Note - this should really do some kind of error checking
    // and exception handling.    
    public void FirstRecord(void)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + tableName +"", con);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            DA.Fill(DS, tableName);

            // Populate the Dictionary for the first row.
            CurrentRecordFields.Empty();
            foreach(var column in DS.Tables[tableName].Columns)
            {
                string columnName = column.ColumnName;
                CurrentRecordFields.Add(columnName,
                    DS.Tables[tableName].Rows[0][columnName].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    // ... and the rest of the navigation methods: prev, next, last, etc.
}

public partial class NavigationForm
{
    private INavigation Navigator {get; set;}

    public NavigationForm(INavigation navigator) :
        base()
    {
        this.Navigator = navigator;
    }

    private void CmdFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use the business logic class to do the DB work.
        // See note above regarding error checking and exception handling.
        Navigator.FirstRecord();

        // Update the UI from the business logic properties.
        this.TxtID.Text = Navigator.CurrentRecordFields["ID"];
        this.TxtFees.Text = Navigator.CurrentRecordFields["Fees"];
        this.TxtFeesHead.Text = Navigator.CurrentRecordFields["FeesHead"];
        this.TxtRemarks.Text = Navigator.CurrentRecordFields["Remarks"];             
    }

    // Etc., for the other form methods.
}
```

Then, when you create the form, you also create an instance of the Navigation business logic class and pass it to the form class constructor.

```
// In the main form or application
private void OnNavigateThroughRecords()
{
    // Create the navigator for the required table.
    INavigation navigator = new Navigation(this.ConectionString, this.SelectedTableName);
    Form navigationForm = new NavigationForm(navigator);
}
```

This isn't a complete example, but it should be enough to get you started.  For more information and plentiful examples, read the many rich resources on the various three-tiered architectures (MVC, MVP and MVVM being amongst the most well known).

**EDIT**

Changed the properties of the Navigator so that an unspecified collection of fields can be presented by the use of the Dictionary class.  This is populated by the Navigator class methods with each entry containing the name of the column as the Key and the value for the record as the Value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Answer !! Id-Fees-FeesHead-Remarks in not fix ! I want to make class for Any Table and any Form which containing any number of fields and any number of textboxes in form !! in Question's first piece of code is running as per my requirement nicely !! but I want to apply this process to my all forms from one class !! I tried it in my second piece of code !! I hope you understand what I want to do sir

Comment: @JemsSaiyed I've edited the answer to provide a more generic solution using a dictionary to map the columns and value for the current record and added parameters to the Navigator constructor to allow the caller to specify the connection string and table name, as per your second code example.

Answer (score 0):

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

namespace APMC
{
     
    class Action_Btn
     {
       
        public void Navigation_Btns(String Con_Str, String Tab_Name, Control form, String Btn_Name,int ID)
        {

            int i = ID;
            List<Control> TB_List = new List<Control>();
            

            foreach (Control childcontrol in form.Controls)
            {

                if (childcontrol is GroupBox)
                {
                    foreach (Control cc in childcontrol.Controls)
                    {
                     

                        if (cc is TextBox)
                        {
                            TB_List.Add(cc); 
                                                  
                        }

                    }
                }
            }



            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Con_Str))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + Tab_Name + "", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, Tab_Name);

                if (Btn_Name == "CmdFirst")
                {

                    if (ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        i = 0;

                        foreach (Control Txt_Name in TB_List)
                        {
                            String field_name = Txt_Name.Name.Substring(3);

                            Txt_Name.Text = ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows[i][field_name].ToString();
                        }


                    }
                    if (i == 0 )
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This is First Record");
                    }



                }

                if (Btn_Name == "CmdNext")
                {
                                  
                    if (i < ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows.Count )
                    {
                    
                   
                        foreach (Control Txt_Name in TB_List)
                        {
                            String field_name = Txt_Name.Name.Substring(3);
                                                
                          Txt_Name.Text = ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows[i][field_name].ToString();
                        }
                            

                          }
                    if (i == ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows.Count)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This is Last Record");
                    }

             
                  
                }

                if (Btn_Name == "CmdPrev")
                {

                    if (i == ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows.Count || i != 1)
                    {
                        i = i - 2;

                        foreach (Control Txt_Name in TB_List)
                        {
                            String field_name = Txt_Name.Name.Substring(3);

                            Txt_Name.Text = ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows[i][field_name].ToString();
                        }


                    }
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This is First Record");
                    }



                }

                if (Btn_Name == "CmdLast")
                {

                    if (ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows.Count - 1 >= i)
                    {
                        i = ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows.Count - 1;

                        foreach (Control Txt_Name in TB_List)
                        {
                            String field_name = Txt_Name.Name.Substring(3);

                            Txt_Name.Text = ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows[i][field_name].ToString();
                        }


                    }
                    if (i == ds.Tables[Tab_Name].Rows.Count)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This is Last Record");
                    }



                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```